# Increase brightness image LabVIEW

Tags: image, labview, brightness

I'm trying to make a program in LabVIEW to adjust the brightness of an image.

I'm increasing the brightness by adding a specific value to every red, green and blue value.
I get that value by my moving the slider.

I have made the program with the formula node but it always gives an error.

I hoped you can help me.

**Block diagrams:**

[image: Block diagram 1]

[image: Block diagram 2]

**Error:**

Error on line 6 is marked by a '#' character: "*...Blue;  int truncate(#int value);     new*"

Comment: labview has a forum that you should check out, as you can upload VIs there. What are you trying to accomplish with `truncate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a function for this shipped with LabVIEW it's called [hilite color](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvpict/hilite_color/):
[image: this image is a snippet that you drag and drop directly to your VI block diagram]

(this image is a snippet that you drag and drop directly to your VI block diagram)

Ton

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I though it was not possible to use C-like functions inside Formula Node. You'd need to use LabVIEW to limit the range. I've attached the screenshot of the equivalent code, but I am sure there's a more efficient way of changing image brightness.

[image: Block Diagram]

Comment: You could remove the most inner for loop (with the 'in range and coerce') since that function accepts array.

Comment: You are right, I cannot use C-like functions in formula node. thx